# Basic Auth in Nuxt JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I've been having hard times trying to implement basic auth in nuxt js app using an existing API from the back-end. I successfully generate a token and login with it but whenever I refresh the browser, I am redirected to the login page despite the fact that token generated and user details are saved in local storage and cookies

My implementation have been based on this example; https://github.com/nuxt/example-auth0

```
// middleware/auth.js 

import { getUserFromCookie, getUserFromLocalStorage, getUserTokenFromCookie, getUserTokenFromLocalStorage } from '~/utils/auth'
import { LOGGIN_USER, SET_TOKEN } from '../utils/mutation-types';

export default function ({ isServer, store, req }) {
  // If nuxt generate, pass this middleware
  if (isServer && !req) return;
  const user = isServer ? getUserFromCookie(req) : getUserFromLocalStorage();
  const token = isServer ? getUserTokenFromCookie(req) : getUserTokenFromLocalStorage();
  store.commit(LOGGIN_USER, user);
  store.commit(SET_TOKEN , token);
}
```

I expect the generated token to be save in the localstorage and when or if expires a refresh token should be use to generate a new token.

Answer (score 1):

What nuxt version are you using? `Context.isServer` has been deprecated and can be `undefined` depending on nuxt version you are using.
If it is the case, changing to `process.server` should fix the problem.